# Stay on the same page after POST action

Tags: php

For example i am editing something here : `127.0.0.1/action.php?id=1`

when i hit confirm button i get redirected to `127.0.0.1/action.php`

**How to stay on the same page: 127.0.0.1/action.php?id=1**

Comment: Use ajax to post the information.

Comment: Do you want to see changes on the page without a postback? If so you might need Ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the `action` attribute of your `<form>` element to that URI. In php, the variable `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` does a nice job at doing this automatically.

```
<form action="<?php echo echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; /* /action.php?id=1 */ ?>" method="POST">
    <!-- ......... form contents .......... -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the query string from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` or from `$_GET` array (if you are using `GET` method). for example

```
header("Location:/action.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);// here it redirects
exit;
```

also like this

```
        // your file name      // query string
 echo "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}";
```